# Exposing the return of method into a property

Tags: c#, mv

How can i expose the return of my method in to a class property?

```
public class BIContactLib: ContactLib
{

   //Expose it here.. to replace the code below

    public IEnumerable<BIContactLib> GetContactLibs 
    {
        get { return (BIContactLib) GetAll}
        set { ; }
    }
}

public class BIContactLibService : IBIRequirement, IDisposable
{
    private ClientContext context = new ClientContext();

  //The return of the method here is the one I would like to expose

    public IEnumerable<BIContactLib> GetAll()
    {
        var contactslib = context.ContactLibs;
        return contactslib.ToList();
    }
}
```

The reason behind this, is I want to create a view model with have the list of contacts library... heres my view model by the way..

```
public class PersonInformation
{
    public BIPerson Person { get; set; }
    public BIAddress Address { get; set; }

    //This is where i want to use it

    public IEnumerable<BIContactLib> GetAll { get; set; }
}
```

Or any other way to do this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
public IEnumerable<BIContactLib> GetContactLibs 
    {
        get { 
             BiContractLib lib = new BiContractLib();
             return lib.GetAll();
            }        
    }
```